# Line with varying slope pivoting on point on other line

Tags: geometry, limits, conic-sections, parametric

The intercept of the normal to an ellipse on its major axis, as its intersection point on the ellipse goes closer and closer to the vertex, reaches a maximum of $\pm\frac{a^2-b^2}{a}$ for a standard ellipse (at the vertex). This can be arrived at by using limits, and is illustrated here graphically (the farthest intercept points are in green, the foci in black) ;
[image]

This wasn't intuitively obvious to me at first; I had the (in hindsight, moronic) notion that the intercept should have gone to infinity as the slope approached 0.

I'd like to know if there's a term for this; a moving line (here, moving because it's parameterized) pivoting around a point on another line, and if there are any related geometric results (not concerning just ellipses, but as general results), since it wasn't intuitively apparent to me at first, and I only noticed it while graphing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You materialize in this way the *envelope of normals*, called the [evolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute) of the initial curve. The evolute of a curve can be described in an equivalent way as the locus of centers of curvature of this curve.

The evolute of the ellipse is known to be a "compressed" astroid with extreme points looking as spikes, 2 of them on the main axis, the 2 others on the secondary axis of the ellipse (see [here](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/e/e070.htm)).

The reciprocal concept is called the ***in**volute*: the ellipse is the involute of the compressed astroid above.

Comment: That's really interesting. I suppose there isn't really anything more to the moving-line-intercepts-point thing, and here it's just that the centers of curvature of the vertices happen to be the two intercept points, right?

Comment: Yes, the way it has appeared to you (moving-line-intercepts-point) was the "top of the iceberg" of this concept. Besides, I realize that I haven't mentionned the evolute as the locus of centers of curvature (it is given in the references): I just added it to my answer.

Comment: I'm probably misreading your last paragraph, but isn't it [another astroid] (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AstroidEvolute.html) that's the evolute of an astroid? And isn't the evolute what you described initially in the answer; how exactly is it its own reciprocal concept?

Comment: Very sorry, I meant "**in**volute" as the reciprocal concept. I correct it. Indeed, the evolute (or involute) of an astroid is another astroid (under the condition that it is a regular astroid, which is not the case for the evolute of the ellipse).

Comment: An interesting curve is the **involute of a circle** used for example in gears' profiles. A good image of it is the successive positions of the endpoint of a string unrolled from a cylinder.